# display data from two different table which don't have any relation?

Tags: sql-server

table1: in that three columns billno, billamt, wno
table2: in that three column chequeentry, chequeamt, wno

i want display the result which is not repeated rows where wno is equal to same
if from table1 i got four rows and from table2 i got two rows. I want display the rows but not repeated. if i use join its done the multiply and show the result and my table2's rows are repeated. But dont want this. it display the null value it i accepted.

i pass the one query i.e join the table

```
select b.billno, b.billamt, c.chequeentry, c.chequeamt 
from t2 as b 
  inner join t3 as c on b.wno=c.wno where b.wno=1
```

i got output but some value are repeated.

Comment: try `select distinct`

Comment: do you have other conditions to be used in the where clause? it will filtered more rows. what is wno? could u give more explanation about the fields. pls provide your query result

Comment: Why have you written `which don't have any relation`? `wno` is the relation between this two table, right?

Comment: i try with the distinct key word but not give any changes @zencv

Comment: i have one photo of this whole problem but not able to attach this question can you give me any email or any source for to directly communicate with you.... wno is my work order number....@cyan

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Full outer Join`, it return both matching, and not matching rows from both tables.

**Syntax**:

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1 FULL OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

Comment: Can you try using DISTINCT,


select DISTINCT b.billno, b.billamt, c.chequeentry, c.chequeamt 
from t2 as b 
  inner join t3 as c on b.wno=c.wno where b.wno=1

Comment: Sir already use that but i not got what i want want.... its display the first table record multiple second table record @skstar